# make gnu - Run targets on parallel

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make

I've this `makefile` and I want to run both targets in **parallel,** automatically just to run `make` and not `make -j...` 
I us the makeflages and NPROCS for each OS inside the make file
(here its for darwin) 
is it possible ?

```
all: module1 module2

NPROCS = $(shell sysctl hw.ncpu  | grep -o '[0-9]\+')
MAKEFLAGS += -j$(NPROCS)

.PHONY: module1
module1:
    @echo "run module 1"
    @echo $(DIR)

.PHONY: module2
module2:
    @echo "run module2”
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, and your makefile will do what you want if `NPROCS > 1` and your platform supports parallel make. See, for instance, the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Options_002fRecursion):

> The MAKEFLAGS variable can also be useful if you want to have certain
>   options, such as ‘-k’ (see Summary of Options), set each time you run
>   make. You simply put a value for MAKEFLAGS in your environment. You
>   can also set MAKEFLAGS in a makefile, to specify additional flags that
>   should also be in effect for that makefile.

And you can also test this yourself, if you wish. The following proves that make runs in parallel mode with `NPROCS+1` recipes. Each recipe prints a first message, sleeps for 2 seconds and prints a second message.

If make runs in parallel mode you should see `NPROCS` `run moduleX with NPROCS=Y` messages printed, and 2 seconds later `NPROCS` `done moduleX` messages. Then you should see one last `run moduleX with NPROCS=Y` message, followed 2 seconds later by a last `done moduleX` message.

Else, if it does not run in parallel mode, you will see an alternation of `run moduleX with NPROCS=Y` messages and `done moduleX` messages.

Demo:

```
$ cat Makefile
SHELL       := bash
NPROCS      := $(shell sysctl hw.ncpu  | grep -o '[0-9]\+')
MAKEFLAGS   += -j$(NPROCS)
MODULES     := $(shell for (( i = 1; i <= $(NPROCS) + 1; i++ )); do printf 'module%d ' "$$i"; done)

.PHONY: all $(MODULES)

all: $(MODULES)

$(MODULES):
    @echo "run $@ with NPROCS=$(NPROCS)"; sleep 2; echo "done $@"

$ make
run module1 with NPROCS=8
run module2 with NPROCS=8
run module3 with NPROCS=8
run module4 with NPROCS=8
run module5 with NPROCS=8
run module6 with NPROCS=8
run module7 with NPROCS=8
run module8 with NPROCS=8
done module2
done module3
done module6
done module8
done module1
done module7
done module4
done module5
run module9 with NPROCS=8
done module9
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! here you change the modules to be `dynamically` , is it possible to keep the structure that I've posted (with target of module1 & module2) and used it as parallel ?

Comment: You can, of course, and it is much simpler. I generated the targets dynamically such that the demo works for any value of `NPROCS`, but you can replace the `MODULES` variable assignment by `MODULES := module1 module2`. You can even suppress this variable and replace all the `$(MODULES)` by `module1 module2`.

Comment: Sorry :) so in this case I not sure what is the difference between what I've posted in the question , it would be great if you can update your answer becouse I miss the delta...

Comment: What I show is a demonstrator that make runs in parallel mode, something that you cannot see with your own makefile. I added a `sleep` command to the recipe such that, looking at the outputs, it is obvious whether make runs the recipes in parallel or not. If not you would see an alternation of `run moduleX with NPROCS=Y` and `done moduleX` messages. See? just a demo, nothing else. It factorizes a bit with one single rule for all `moduleX` targets and the automatic generation of `NPROCS+1` module targets for better demonstration, but nothing important. Ignore it if you prefer.

Comment: The only important part of my answer is the first word: "_Yes_". Please ignore the rest if it does not make sense for you.

Comment: Thanks, just to verify , so you say that the code should work in parallel `as-is` (as in my question ) ?

Comment: Yes, if `NPROCS > 1` and your platform supports parallel make.

Comment: **NO**! `NPROCS` is indeed set. `-j12` (say) is added to `MAKEFLAGS`. However, this does _not_ cause _make_ to run its jobs in parallel. Make 4.2.1 on Linux and cygwin. Are you sure this test is working for you?

Comment: @bobbogo: tested with GNU make 4.1 on MacOS and debian stretch. It works as expected. `make NPROCS=4` runs 4 jobs in parallel plus one last fifth job after the others. `make NPROCS=1` runs only one job plus one second after the first one. Why do you claim that it does not work? Did you first check that your OS supports parallel make at all?